# Save returning true, object not being saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Save returning true, object not being saved. I can't really tell why. I suspect I need to explicitly tell rails it is modifiable but I am not sure how. Any idea what can be wrong?

## view

```
<%= form_tag(set_email_settings_path) do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <% if @logged_in_profile.email_settings != 'off' %>
      <%= submit_tag 'Turn off emails', class: 'btn btn-default btn-about', name: 'email_notification' %>
    <% else %>
      <%= submit_tag 'Turn on emails', class: 'btn btn-default btn-about', name: 'email_notification' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

## controller

```
if params[:email_notification] == 'Turn off emails'
  logged_in_profile.email_settings = 'off'
else
  logged_in_profile.email_settings = 'normal'
end
if logged_in_profile.save
  redirect_to email_settings_path
else
  redirect_to settings_path
end
```

## route

```
  post "set_email_settings" => "profiles#set_email_settings", :as => 'set_email_settings'
```

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: try printing the model's `errors`

Comment: try this and check errors logged_in_profile.errors.full_messages

Comment: is there a way to print errors from the controller? I looked at the logs and there is no sign of error =c

Comment: Is `logged_in_profile` actually being made into an object. Where is `logged_in_profile` being made into an object? I ask because I cannot see the full controller

Comment: Also, if an `logged_in_profile` entry already exists, would you not update the attributes, rather than save? Sorry, it is just hard to see the full picture

Answer (score 1):

Try this as the form instead, because I do not think you are submitting any values in the form...

```
<%= form_tag(set_email_settings_path) do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <% if @logged_in_profile.email_settings == 'normal' %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag 'email_notification', 'Turn off emails' %>
      <%= submit_tag 'Turn off emails', class: 'btn btn-default btn-about' %>
    <% else %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag 'email_notification', 'Turn on emails' %>
      <%= submit_tag 'Turn on emails', class: 'btn btn-default btn-about' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

You will see above, I changed removed the '!='; just good practice to avoid '!='. If there was not an 'else', 'unless' could also be used `<% unless @logged_in_profile.email_settings == 'off' %>`.

Comment: The issue was I need a variable with an @ sign in the controller. I am confused. IT works now. somehow

Comment: Ar okay. I was wondering what `logged_in_profile` was on its own, as it needs to be made as an Object before you can do anything on it. `@` just creates an instance variable so it can be carried into View. Please put your solution as an answer, so the question is complete. Also please put the full action from the Controller, as it is confusing without the full story